# Prob. 12, Sec. 4.2, in Bartle & Sherbert's INTRO TO REAL ANALYSIS: If $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x, y$ and if $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ exists, . . .

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits, proof-verification

Here is Prob. 12, Sec. 4.2, in the book *[Introduction To Real Analysis](https://sciencemathematicseducation.files.wordpress.com/2014/01/0471433314realanalysis4.pdf)* by Robert G. Bartle and Donald R. Sherbert, 4th edition:

> Let $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be such that $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$ for all $x, y$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Assume that $\lim_{x \to 0} f = L$ exists. Prove that $L = 0$, and then prove that $f$ has a limit at every point $c \in \mathbb{R}$. [*Hint:* First note that $f(2x) = f(x) + f(x) = 2 f(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Also note that $f(x) = f(x-c) + f(c)$ for $x, c$ in $\mathbb{R}$.]

My Attempt:

> As $\lim_{x \to 0} f (x) = L$, so, given any real number $\varepsilon > 0$, we can find a real number $\delta > 0$ such that 
>   $$ \lvert f(x) - L \rvert < \varepsilon \tag{1} $$
>   for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ for which 
>   $$ 0 < \lvert x - 0 \rvert < \delta; \tag{2} $$
>   therefore, we can also conclude that, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ for which 
>   $$ 0 <  \lvert x - 0 \rvert < \frac{\delta}{2} $$ 
>   holds, for those $x$ we also have 
>   $$ 0 <  \lvert 2x - 0 \rvert < \delta, $$ 
>   and so 
>   $$ \lvert f(2x) - L \rvert < \varepsilon, $$
>   and thus it follows that $$ \lim_{x \to 0} f(2x) = L $$
>   also. But as $f(2x) = 2 f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, so we must have 
>   $$ \lim_{x \to 0} f(2x) = 2 \lim_{x \to 0} f(x), $$
>   that is we must have 
>   $$ L = 2L,$$
>   which in turn implies that $L = 0$. 
>   Hence $$ \lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0 $$
>   holds.

Am I right? Is this part of the proof correct and clear enough?

> Now for any real numbers $c, x$, we find that 
>   $$ f(x) = f(x-c + c) = f(x-c) + f(c), $$
>   and so 
>   $$ f(x) - f(c) = f(x-c). $$
>   Now if $x= c$, then we obtain 
>   $$ f(c) - f(c) = f(c-c) $$
>   or $$ f(0) = 0. $$
>   Then using (1) and (2) above, we find that, for every real number $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a real number $\delta > 0$ such that 
>   $$ \lvert f(x) - f(c) \rvert = \lvert f(x-c) \rvert < \varepsilon $$
>   for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ for which 
>   $$ 0 < \lvert x-c \rvert < \delta. $$
>   Therefore we can conclude that 
>   $$ \lim_{x \to c} f(x) = f(c). $$

Is this proof sound enough in each and every detail hereof?

Answer (score 1):

## Proof

Since $$f(x)+f(y)=f(x+y),~~~\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R},\tag1$$
hence $$f(x)+f(x)=f(x+x),~~~\forall x\in \mathbb{R},\tag2$$
namely $$2f(x)=f(2x),~~~\forall x\in \mathbb{R}.\tag3$$
Let $x \to 0$ and take the limits of the both sides of $(3)$. We obtain $$2L=2\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)=\lim_{x \to 0}2f(x)=\lim_{x \to 0}f(2x)=L,$$which shows that $$L=0.$$

Moreover, from $(1)$ we may obtain $$f(c)+f(x-c)=f(x),~~~\forall x,c \in \mathbb{R},\tag4$$where $c$ is any a constant. Likewise, let $x \to c$ and take the limits of both sides of $(4).$ We obtain $$f(c)+0=\lim_{x \to c}f(c)+\lim_{x \to c}f(x-c)=\lim_{x \to c}[f(c)+f(x-c)]=\lim_{x \to c}f(x),$$namely $$\lim_{x \to c}f(x)=f(c),$$which shows that $f(x)$ has a limit $f(c)$ at $x=c$, in another word, it is continuous at $x=c.$ We are done!

Comment: This proof I can offer a genuine critique! Where did you use the fact that $L$ exists (is finite)? This proof doesn't use epsilon deltas so it's not really clear where you use this but we know that we have to use it somewhere... otherwise why would the authors have wrote it in the assumptions? It is tucked into $L=2L \implies L=0$. Note that $L=2L$ really implies that $L$ is either zero or infinity.

Comment: @mason Don't you know the  rules of limits？ If not， I would not post any more comments.

Comment: I don't have to post any comments if you prefer it. But I am not sure what limit rule you are referring to... maybe you can teach me...

Comment: @Mason Considering the CONTEXT of the problem, we should assume that $L$ is a finite limit. If not, can you prove $L=0$? which teacher told you that?

Comment: Indeed! Nice proof.